# My linq select does not work, my foreach does

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ `Select` which does not work.

```
Data.Select(d => d.Value.IsDirty = true); //-- Not working
```

My longer workaround does.

```
foreach (var d in Data)
    d.Value.IsDirty = true;
```

Why does my first code not work?

Comment: *bang head on the wall*: LINQ = query!

Comment: Dont produce side effects using LINQ. As the name suggests, it is to just Query but not for changing the state.

Comment: Sandeep is correct; you are doing something that LINQ was *specifically designed to not do*.  Use queries to *ask questions about data*. Use loops to *make changes to data*. Never, *ever* use a query to change a data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Select()` returns an `IEnumerable<…>`, which has the *ability* to iterate over the input and invoke the code in question, but doesn't actually do so until you enumerate it in some manner:

```
Data.Select(d => d.Value.IsDirty = true).ToList();
```

or

```
foreach (var _ in Data.Select(d => d.Value.IsDirty = true))
    ; // Do nothing
```

However, given that they perform side effects (obviously the intent here), both of the above are bad karma. Don't use them. Your original `foreach` is the only sensible choice.

Comment: Both of these are disgusting. The correct answer is of the form "you're doing it wrong by trying to use a query to change state; instead, use the `foreach` loop."

Comment: @Jason: I've amended my question to make my position clearer. But, "disgusting"? We're discussing programming techniques, not fetish porn.

Answer (score 9):

Projection functions like `Select`, `Where`, etc. define *queries*. Simply calling `Select` does not actually *do* anything until the query is evaluated (almost certainly, at some point, by a `foreach`).

If you were to do something to force execution of the query (calling `Count`, for instance), you'd see it take effect.

It is, however, a bit of an abuse. These functions aren't specifically intended for state-altering operations.

Comment: Ahhhh, makes sense. It worked for me when I toList()'ed the query. And nice touch about the state-altering point. I do use it quite a bit for that although it might not be it's originally stated intend :P

Answer (score -3):

Calling `Select` does not cause the side effect you need, even if you force execution by iterating over the elements.
If you want the side effect you have to do `foreach`.

For example:

```
class MyValue
{
    public MyValue(bool flag) { Flag = flag; }

    public bool Flag { get; set; }
}

class MyValueContainer
{
    public MyValueContainer(MyValue val) { MyVal = val; }

    public MyValue MyVal { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someList = new List<MyValueContainer>();
        someList.Add(new MyValueContainer(new MyValue(true)));
        someList.Add(new MyValueContainer(new MyValue(true)));
        someList.Add(new MyValueContainer(new MyValue(false)));
        someList.Add(new MyValueContainer(new MyValue(true)));

        var trueCount = someList.Count(x => x.MyVal.Flag); // 3
        var falseCount = someList.Count(x => !x.MyVal.Flag); // 1

        // try causing side effect by calling Select
        someList.Select(x => x.MyVal.Flag = false);

        // force execution. call Count
        trueCount = someList.Count(x => x.MyVal.Flag); // still 3... no side effect.
        falseCount = someList.Count(x => !x.MyVal.Flag); // still 1... no side effect.

        foreach (var x in someList)
            x.MyVal.Flag = false;

        trueCount = someList.Count(x => x.MyVal.Flag); // 0... side effect seen.
        falseCount = someList.Count(x => !x.MyVal.Flag); // 4...  side effect seen.
    }
}
```

Comment: -1. You aren't forcing execution of the query (you are, in fact, not even storing the query anywhere). This is simply incorrect; `Select` *can* cause side effects, it's just smelly code if you use it that way. If you were to put `someList.Select(x => x.MyVal.Flag = false).Count();`, you would see the side effect in your subsequent tests.